# Concurrent hash map in java that shrinks when keys are deleted?

Tags: java, concurrency, hashmap

Java's [ConcurrentHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) expands dynamically when needed. I assume like the other java collections, the internal storage of the `ConcurrentHashMap` will not shrink when keys are deleted (please correct me if I'm wrong, I can't see anything in the spec that would suggest it will shrink). I'm going to be creating many `ConcurrentHashMaps` whose size may often grow then shrink significantly. This is for a large cache so limiting memory usage is important. I'm therefore looking for:

1. A hashmap implementation in java which supports more-or-less unsynchronised/non-blocking gets whilst being thread safe as multiple
   threads will do get and put (so like ConcurrentHashMap does already).
2. Shrinks it's internal storage automatically when say 75% of the internal table slots are empty (75% is just an example figure, any
   sensible percentage is OK).

Does anyone know of a suitable implementation?

I can't see any method of retrieving the current `'capacity'` of ConcurrentHashMap, to allow me to just delete and recreate it when its entries become too spare.

Comment: You didn't specify a time cost requirement, so would ConcurrentSkipListMap work? It's log(n).

Comment: One could do `map = new HashMap<>(map)` so to create such a class oneself is feasible, overriding `put` and `remove`. For the rest: hash maps buckets will not be reorganized during a map's life time. You could try a **TreeMap**.

Comment: The reason why there isn't a ConcurrentTreeMap is that maintaining the concurrency properties of ConcurrentHashMap with a TreeMap is very difficult. But if a high level of concurrency is not a requirement, then TreeMap wrapped in some synchronization would be a good choice.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I was looking at this for running an in-memory cache; on further research it appears that a proper caching library, e.g. Caffeine (https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine) might suit my needs.